ValueError: Need either a `state_dict` or a `save_folder` containing offloaded weights while trying to run the transformer.pipeline for Llama-3.1-8B
I tried to run "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct" model on MAC M2 but getting error while running below code:
model = "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)    
transformers.pipeline( "text-generation", 
model=model, 
torch_dtype=torch.float16,  
device_map="auto") 

Following Error is thrown while executing transformers.pipeline(...)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site- packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py:
895,

raise ValueError("Need either a `state_dict` or a `save_folder` containing offloaded weights.") ValueError: Need either a `state_dict` or a `save_folder` containing offloaded weights.

I tried following options to resolve:

Passed offload_folder="save_folder" in from_pretrained and pipeline both:

   tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model,offload_folder="save_folder")    
   transformers.pipeline( "text-generation", 
   model=model, 
   torch_dtype=torch.float16,  
   device_map="auto", offload_folder="save_folder") 


Tried Passing state_dict={} in transformers.pipeline()

